# Can Z3 effectively solve constraints with a max operation?

Tags: z3, solver, z3py

Suppose I want to solve the following constraint: `y == max(x, 0)`. What I could think of is to encode the following (in z3py interface): `If(x > 0, y == x, y == 0)`. My questions were:

1. Is Z3 internally going to translate the above expression into two constraints: `x > 0 /\ y == x` and `x <= 0 /\ y == 0`, and then takes an **OR** of them and returns sat when either of the two constraints is satisfiable?
2. If so, seems like the number of constraints will grow exponentially with the number of `max` operations. I have a system with over 100 `max`. Is there an efficient way of solving it, either in Z3 or any other solvers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using the python interface you can define:

```
def mymax(x,y):
    return If(x > y, x, y)
```

This does not produce an exponential number of constraints.

In many situations it suffices to just enforce one side of the inequalities mandated by max. In these cases introduce a fresh variable max_x_y and assert

```
   max_x_y >= x, max_x_y >= y
```

When you require also that max_x_y <= max(x,y), then the standard approach with Z3 is to use mymax instead of introducing fresh variables.

Comment: With `mymax`, if I want to express `y` is the max between `x` and `0`, I could do `solve(y==mymax(x, 0))`, which is cool. But is Z3 internally going to translate mymax into two constraints and *OR* them together and to return sat when either is satisfiable? Iff so, although `If` makes it look like just one constraint, does Z3 treat it like two constraints and thus makes complexity grow exponentially?

Comment: @queeten The runtime may or may not grow exponentially depending on the structure of the problem.  See the comments on my answer.  Correct me if I'm wrong here Nikolaj.  Also, interesting point regarding possibly using just one side of the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

If all your max operation appear in a context of the form `y > max(x, 0)`, I would encode them as `(and (> y x) (> y 0))` (SMT-LIB), which has no branching. I'm not sure what the syntax is for this using the Python interface.

Comment: This is a nice trick! But how would you do `y == max(x, 0)` though? Is there a general way of expressing `max` effectively without a branch?

Comment: The most concise way to do it is how Nikolaj said, `If(x > y, x, y)`.  I doubt you can say in general whether the search space will be doubled by introducing constraints like that.  It depends on the problem and the internals of the solver.  If `x > y` is known from elsewhere in the problem then Z3 will effectively replace `If(x > y, x, y)` with just `x` or `y` and there will be no branch.  If `x > y` can't be determined from the context, then it may have to be branched on.

Comment: In this type of situation knowledge about the solvers and algorithms can help you hypothesize about what the impact on performance will be.  However, the overall performance of a solver like Z3 is complicated and depends on many factors weighed off against each other.  In general, you have to test your hypotheses with relevant benchmarks to determine whether they are borne out in reality for your specific problems of interest.